# Proving the role of countable chain condition - what is this quote saying?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

> The importance of antichains in forcing is that for most purposes,
>   dense sets and maximal antichains are equivalent. A maximal antichain
>   $A$ is one that cannot be extended and still be an antichain. This means
>   every element of $p ∈ P$ is compatible with some member of $A$. Their
>   existence follows from Zorn's lemma. Given a maximal antichain $A$, let
>   $D = \{ p : ( \exists q \in A ) ( p≤q ) \}$. $D$ is dense, and $G∩D≠0$ if and only if $G∩A≠0$.
>   Conversely, given a dense set $D$, Zorn's lemma shows there exists a
>   maximal antichain $A⊆D$, and then $G∩D≠0$ if and only if $G∩A≠0$.
>    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forcing_(mathematics)#The_countable_chain_condition

I really don't understand what this is saying. First of all,

> This means every element of p ∈ P is compatible with some member of A.

I mean, how can "every" $p$ is compatible with some member of $A$ when $A$ is antichain? Aren't elements of $A$ also in $P$? Then how can members of $A$ be compatible with each other when the definition of antichain says they are not compatible?

Comment: Oops. I just realized that G is already mentioned in the paragraphs above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is a *maximal antichain*, then for every $p \in P$ there are two options: either $p \in A$ (whence $p$ is compatible with an element of $A$, namely itself), or $p \notin A$ (whence $A \cup \{ p \}$ is not an antichain, meaning that there are distinct $q,r \in A \cup \{ p \}$ which are compatible, and since $A$ is an antichain exactly one of $q$ and $r$ is $p$).

The definition of an antichain is that any two *dinstinct* elements of that set are incompatible; every condition is clearly compatible with itself.